# Wireshark: Internet Control Message Protocol

Tags: wireshark

I've installed Wireshark on my Windows machine, and to my knowledge, the section at the bottom represents the packets in their octal and ASCII form. When I click on the IP version & the header length (20B), Wireshark highlights 45, which is 69 in decimal and E in ASCII. Could someone please explain this? Thank you.

[image: Wireshark ss]

Comment: _[RFC 791, Internet Protocol, Section 3.1. Internet Header Format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc791#section-3.1)_ has a diagram of the IPv4 header and an explanation for each header field. If you are going to look at such thing with Wireshark, you need to get familiar with the RFCs.

Answer (score 3):

Both *IP version* and *header length* are four-bit headers, located within the same octet.

Indicating insignificant digits with `.`, hexadecimal `4.` or binary `0100....` indicates IPv4, and hex `.5` or bin `....0101`indicates five 32-bit words or twenty octets.